# Can Loki accept/combine a log stream (unique set of labels) from multiple Promtail instances running simultaneously? (applies to Prometheus too)

Tags: amazon-ec2, monitoring, prometheus, logging

I am using `ec2_sd_configs` in Loki (and Prometheus) to discover my EC2 instances, most of which are autoscaled, and therefore come and go.  They are identical load balanced API instances, so I don't care to distinguish one from another.  I *do* need to distinguish other non-autoscaled hosts in the VPC from one another, however.

Currently I have the `instance` label for various jobs' streams set to `<instanceNameTagValue>:<private_ip>`.  The autoscaled hosts have a Name tag that is propagated by the launch template (thus giving them all the same `Name` tag value), so they'll all have `instance` labels like `my-autoscaled-app:10.x.x.x`, and thus I can perform log stream selection by regex in LogQL queries, and find all my autoscaled instances. I'm ensuring a separate log stream per host, which is something I *assumed* I needed to do, to avoid timestamp collision and possible de-duplication.  This labeling scheme is very annoying, since Loki fills up with all the old, scaled-in instance `instance` labels, of which there are now about a hundred after a month.

What happens if I have multiple instances of Promtail, 1 per instance, pushing the same label set?  e.g. the `instance` and `job` labels, from 8 ec2 instances, are `my-autoscaled-app` and `syslog`.

Will Loki combine these into one stream, eliminating the need I currently have to give each host a unique `instance` label, which requires the use of a regex on this label to perform log stream selection in my LogQL queries to combine the logs for these autoscaled instances?

If not, is there some way I can combine log streams (i.e., a unique set of labels) from multiple Promtails running on different hosts into a single stream, without losing data?